# Conformal Ward Identity (Di Francesco et al)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions, ward-identity

In the yellow pages (Conformal Field Theory, Di Francesco, Mathieu, Sénéchal), the authors derive the conformal Ward identity in the following way:

1. They show that, for a conformal transformation,
   $$ \partial_\mu (\epsilon_\nu T^{\mu \nu}) = \epsilon_\nu  \partial_\mu T^{\mu \nu}  + \dfrac12 \partial_\rho \epsilon^\rho  \eta_{\mu \nu} T^{\mu \nu} + \dfrac12 \epsilon^{\alpha \beta} \partial_\alpha \epsilon_\beta \epsilon_{\mu \nu} T^{\mu \nu}. \tag{5.42}$$
2. "Integrating both sides of (5.42)", they find
   $$ \delta_\epsilon \langle{X}\rangle= \int_M d^2x \, \partial_\mu \langle{T^{\mu \nu }(x)\epsilon_\nu(x)X}\rangle. \tag{5.44}  $$

I don't understand how this last equality is derived from step 1). The domain $M$ is taken to include the positions of all the fields contained in $X$.

Comment: Divergence aka Stokes' theorem, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem recently. Here is my argument.

For simplicity, let $X = \phi(y)$ be a primary field. Start from

$$\int_M d^2x \; \partial_{\mu}\langle T^{\mu\nu}(x)\epsilon_{\nu}(x)\phi(y)\rangle $$
where $M$ includes $y$. By (5.42), it becomes
$$\int_M d^2x \; \epsilon_{\nu} \langle\partial_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu} \phi(y)\rangle  + \frac{1}{2}(\partial \cdot \epsilon) \langle {T^{\mu}}_{\mu}\phi(y)\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\epsilon_{\beta} \langle\varepsilon_{\mu\nu}T^{\mu\nu}\phi(y)\rangle$$
where $\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta}$ is Levi-Civita symbol and $\epsilon^{\alpha}$ is the infinitesimal displacement.

By (5.32) in the same book, it becomes
$$- \int_{M} d^2x \; \delta(x-y) \bigg( \epsilon_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\langle\phi(y)\rangle + \frac{1}{2}(\partial\cdot\epsilon)\Delta \langle \phi(y)\rangle + i \frac{s}{2}\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\epsilon_{\beta}\langle\phi(y)\rangle \bigg) \\
 = -\epsilon_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\langle\phi(y)\rangle - \frac{1}{2}(\partial\cdot\epsilon)\Delta \langle \phi(y)\rangle - i \frac{s}{2}\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\epsilon_{\beta}\langle\phi(y)\rangle $$
Now, we switch into the complex coordinate: $z = x^{1} + ix^{2}$. Then,
$$\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\epsilon_{\beta} = \partial_1\epsilon_2 - \partial_2\epsilon_1 = \frac{1}{i}(\partial_z \epsilon^{z} - \partial_{\bar{z}}\epsilon^{\bar{z}})$$
where we've defined $\epsilon^{z} = \epsilon^1 + i \epsilon^2$.

For the sake of convenience, we denote $\partial_z \to \partial ,\partial_{\bar{z}} \to \bar{\partial} $ and the same way for $\epsilon$. Also, recall that, from (5.21) in the same book:  $\Delta = h + \bar{h}$ and $s = h - \bar{h}$, in which $h$ and $\bar{h}$ are the conformal weights. As a result,

$$-\bigg(\epsilon\partial + \bar{\epsilon}\bar{\partial} + \frac{1}{2}(\partial\epsilon + \bar{\partial}\bar{\epsilon})(h+\bar{h}) + \frac{1}{2}(\partial\epsilon - \bar{\partial}\bar{\epsilon})(h-\bar{h})\bigg)\langle \phi \rangle \\
= -\bigg[(\epsilon\partial + h\partial\epsilon) - (\bar{\epsilon}\bar{\partial} + \bar{h}\bar{\partial}\bar{\epsilon}) \bigg] \langle \phi \rangle $$

Recall (5.23), it is indeed $\delta_{\epsilon,\bar{\epsilon}}\langle\phi\rangle$ as the author claims.